# How to find overfitting and underfitting in k-means clustering algorithm for text classification?

Tags: testing, cluster-analysis, k-means, text-classification, overfitting-underfitting

I've used K-means clustering algorithm but I have no idea about underfitting and overfitting.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Overfitting and underfitting are relevant only in a supervised setting. I assume that you use clustering in an unsupervised setting, so these problems are irrelevant.